# ¿Cómo validar usuario y mail únicos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Tengo un formulario en el que estoy intentando por activa y por pasiva poder validar si el nombre o el correo son únicos, es decir, que en la `database` no estén repetidos. y si lo están, tengas que cambiarlos sobre la marcha:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="nick">Nick</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nickname" class="nick" required maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for=email>Email</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" name="email" class="email" required maxlength="150"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for=passwd>Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="passwd" class="passwd" required maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="snd_passwd" class="snd_passwd" required maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><!--<input class="form-btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Suscribe"/>--></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

El formulario es sencillo, pero he estado probando con Jquery y PHP y en ninguno de los dos obtengo resultado.

Lo primero con jquery fue añadiendo lo siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       (function($) {
           $('.nick').keyup(function () {
                let ValorBusqueda = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
                $('.BusquedaRapida tr').hide();
                 $('.BusquedaRapida tr').filter(function () {
                    return ValorBusqueda.test($(this).text());
                  }).show();
                    })
          }(jQuery));
    });
    </script>
```

Ya que con PHP no me gusta nada, prefiero olvidarme del tema por ahora...

Comment: No entiendo, para ser la validacion no es solo mandar la peticion con el form, y en tu controlador que recibe esta, haga una consulta a la BD para verificar si existe o no el email o usuario?

Comment: Mucho me temo para esas verificaciones necesitas PHP, porque desde el cliente y solo con Javascript no podrás acceder a la base de datos. Lo ideal es que ejecutes una petición por AJAX cuando haya cambios en esos dos campos.